# Javascript seems not working to load image when page loads

Tags: javascript, forms, load

I'm using Javascript to make my checkboxes larger. Doing this I use image one for black checkbox and another one with the checked checkbox. It works like the real checkbox. However, when the page loads, the black checkboxes are not successfully loaded unless I click somewhere in the page to invoke them. Please check [here](http://checkintonight.freeiz.com/) to the page.

Belowing is my js code which I think it will impact this:

```
var Custom = {
    init: function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), span = Array(), textnode, option, active;
        for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
            if((inputs[a].type == "checkbox" || inputs[a].type == "radio") && inputs[a].className == "styled") {
                span[a] = document.createElement("span");
                span[a].className = inputs[a].type;

                if(inputs[a].checked == true) {
                    if(inputs[a].type == "checkbox") {
                        span[a].style.background = unchecked;
                    } else {
                        span[a].style.background = unchecked;
                    }
                }
                inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
                inputs[a].onchange = Custom.clear;
                if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                    span[a].onmousedown = Custom.pushed;
                    span[a].onmouseup = Custom.check;
                } else {
                    span[a].className = span[a].className += " disabled";
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Below is my image on form load:
[image]

And this  is my page when clicking on anywhere:
[image]
Which other functions and variables are already defined. Thus could anyone help me to enable them to display whenever the form loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found a bug in my Javascript code. I add the `else` statement in the `init()` function to test if the checkbox is also not checked. So the code becomes like below:

```
if(inputs[a].checked == true) {
    if(inputs[a].type == "checkbox") {
          span[a].style.background = unchecked;
    }
} else {
    span[a].style.background = unchecked;
}
```

Then it works! Thanks everyone that reviewed and answered to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't known why you use that

```
    if(inputs[a].checked == true) {
       if(inputs[a].type == "checkbox") {
           span[a].style.background = unchecked;
       } else {
           span[a].style.background = unchecked;
       }
   }
```

But when I open your script in http://checkintonight.freeiz.com/js/custom-form-elements.js
Try to call function clear() in end of Custom.init(), it works

```
init: function() {
  //
  ...
  //
  this.clear();
}
```

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: the above else is just a radio button which I'll use it later the code. However, using this.clear() will remove all the background and show only the default checkboxes. What I want is to load all background on page load.